# What would you call the "opposite" of a cumulative distribution function?

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function

A cumulative distribution function is a function that returns probabilities of $X$ being smaller than or equal to some value $x$:

$$Pr(≤)=()$$

What would you call a distribution function that returns probabilities $X$ being **greater** than or equal to some value $x$, i.e.,

$$Pr(≥)=()$$

?

Comment: "Opposite" could mean many things -- e.g. from just your title I was guessing you might have been after the functional inverse of the cdf.  The *complement* of a cdf, $F_X(x) = P(X\leq x)$ is the survivor function (a.k.a. survival function), $S(x) = 1-F_X(x) = P(X>x)$. If you include the equality in both events, they're not complementary, though.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_function#Definition . You might call $P(X\geq x)$ an *upper tail probability*, but that term is also used for $S(x)$.

Comment: The functional inverse of a CDF i.e. $F^{-1}(p)$ (your title not your text) is the [quantile function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantile_function)